# Java - Allocated memory vs high memory utilization (Elasticsearch)

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster running on 9 nodes 5 data 3 master.

Initially the allocated heapspace to elastic was 2g on every node and each node is a VM with around 58g of memory.

Yesterday one of my node went down, and the entire cluster blackedout. All I could find in the ES logs looked like:

`[WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [xxxxxXXxxxx] [gc][young][4109765][392598] duration [13.5s], collections [1]/[3.9s], total [13.5s]/[50.5m], memory [1.4gb]->[1.5gb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [456.8mb]->[543.3mb]/[546.1mb]}{[survivor] [9mb]->[9mb]/[68.2mb]}{[old] [1gb]->[1gb]/[1.3gb]}`

Now I was not even able to login (ssh) into this instance and it was holding my entire cluster at ransom. Breaking the whole pipeline.

When I checked the server logs I could see a spike in memory consumption which went from a mere 30% to 99.98% over a couple of hours. This was processed post a restart

Here I have the following questions

When I allocate a 2g memory to a process, how can that process exceed and consume upto 90% of available memory.

How do I guarantee that my cluster does not fail if one of my nodes fails.

For the second part I got some info from: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23939

Which states: 
When the cluster forms again after long GC / network disconnects, and the master allocates the shards to the problematic node, the node first has to properly shutdown the existing shard resources. This can take a while, depending on the operations that were previously running. This manifests in the ShardLock failures, as the new shard instance cannot be created while the old one is not fully cleaned up. We are currently investigating how we can provide more insight into which types of operations are preventing the old shard instance from being released, which will require code changes.

How do I prevent this from causing a blackout on my cluster?

Answer (score 1):

**Couple of questions:**

1: "Initially the allocated heap space to elastic was 2g on every node". Does this mean you only set '-Xms2g'?? Not -Xmx?

2: Why only 2GB of mem for Elasticsearch when there is 58GB available?

3: "When I allocate a 2g memory to a process, how can that process exceed and consume upto 90% of available memory." How did you notice that it consumes more? (Also linked to first question)

**Reasoning behind questions:**

1: "Ensure that the min (Xms) and max (Xmx) sizes are the same to prevent the heap from resizing at runtime, a very costly process." (From ES [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#heap-sizing))

2: Try to give [half of your memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#_give_less_than_half_your_memory_to_lucene) to ES and the other half to OS

Comment: 1) Initially I meant by default. I had no idea about giving it the half of available memory, till I actually read that article you mention earlier. I have OS logs which suspect that elasticsearch process bought the node down (High memory consumption)

Comment: Also I have specified only one node in spark es.nodes configuration, thinking that spark and es are smart enough to sniff the entire cluster (as mentioned in the docs). To my unfortunate badluck, this is the very same node which misbehaved.

Comment: Both Xms and Xms were set to 2